# Get all tweets to user python-twitter

Tags: twitter, python-twitter

Is there a way to get a list of all tweets sent to a twitter user?

I know I can get all tweets sent by the user using `api.GetUserTimeline(screen_name='realDonaldTrump')`, but is there a way to retrieve tweets to that user?

Comment: Sorted using `api.GetSearch(raw_query='q=to%3ArealDonaldTrump')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use: `api.GetSearch(raw_query='q=to%3ArealDonaldTrump')`